# Best Linux distro for load-balancers?

Tags: linux, load-balancing, virtual-machines

I wanted to try HAProxy/Linux Virtual Server like front-end load-balancers, but as far I know, they're Linux-based software. I don't have any experiences with Linux yet. so there're quite many questions to ask:

- What is the best Linux distro(s) for load-balancing?
- I plan to use VirtualPC to run some virtual machines. How much RAM is the best for each machine run that distro? I want to simulate a load-balancer which can handle about 100 hits/second, is it possible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The best distro for *anything* is the one with which you have the most experience configuring and administering.  Beyond that, they're all pretty similar.

I'd say use something like Ubuntu server LTS release, or CentOS 5.4.  Both good stable distributions, with good community support, and a regular release pattern.

You should probably look at a better virtualization solution than VirtualPC.  If you're already using linux, then KVM is a pretty natural choice. 
As for RAM utilisation, think about how much you want for the base system (2-4G), then add how much you want for however many virtual machines you want (say, 4 VMs, 2G each => 8G additional RAM)

I've just re-read your question, and notice that you don't have any linux experience so far.  In this case, you'll probably find Ubuntu the most easy to get started with, it has the most comprehensive forums, IRC Channels and HowTo pages.  I've been using Ubuntu for a good number of years on desktops and servers and still find apt-get package management hard to beat.

Comment: I expected a small-fast distro, because they not actually run the web server. Can you suggest me more? :)

Comment: Ubuntu or CentOS can be small fast distros.  I can get ubuntu to boot in less than a minute, by carefully tuning the configuration not to include any unnecessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

For a load balancer, debian installed off the netinst sources, minimal installation.  Install ssh, ipvs and configure.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't have any experience with it yet, for someone who is complete new to Linux and has no idea how to set this stuff up from the ground up, I've heard good things about the Zen Load Balancer which is a debian based distro that has web management and all that. Again, I haven't used it but you can find more info about it at http://www.zenloadbalancer.com/

Answer (score 0):

Load balancing in most cases is done in kernel space and controlled via `tc` command from `iproute2` package.

Any distro would do. If you have no experience with Linux go with something mainstream like Debian

Answer (score -4):

The choice of the best Linux distribution for load balancers depends on various factors, including your specific needs, expertise, and preferences. However, some popular and widely used Linux distributions for load balancers are:

**Ubuntu Server:** Ubuntu is known for its user-friendly interface and extensive community support. It has a robust server edition optimized for performance and scalability, making it a popular choice for load balancers.

**CentOS:** CentOS is a stable and reliable distribution based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL). It is well-suited for server deployments and provides long-term support, which is crucial for load balancers.

**Debian:** Debian is a versatile and stable Linux distribution with a focus on free and open-source software. Its solid reputation for stability makes it a good option for load balancers.

**Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL):** RHEL is a commercial Linux distribution that offers excellent support and security features. For organizations that prioritize enterprise-level support, RHEL can be a top choice.

**Fedora Server:** Fedora is a cutting-edge distribution that serves as a testing ground for features later incorporated into RHEL. If you want to stay on the leading edge of technology, Fedora can be a suitable option.

**OpenSUSE:** OpenSUSE is a community-driven distribution known for its stability and versatility. It has server editions that can be tailored for load balancer deployments.

**Alpine Linux:** If you need a lightweight and minimalist Linux distribution for your load balancers, Alpine Linux can be a good fit. It is designed for efficiency and security, making it suitable for resource-constrained environments.

Remember that the effectiveness of a load balancer relies not only on the Linux distribution but also on the software you choose to handle the load balancing, such as Nginx, HAProxy, or others. Additionally, configuring load balancers properly and considering your specific requirements are crucial in making the best choice for your load balancing needs.

Comment: Looks like a completely useless generic post from  a spam profile

Comment: SpamGPT rules :( We see more and more of that.